# AngularJS ui-bootstrap modal instance issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have AngularJS app (version 1.4.7) and latest version of ui.bootstrap. Problem occurs when I try to inject $uibModalInstance which throws error `Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider`

Here is controller code:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @param $uibModal
 */
function ClientsController($uibModal)
{
    var _this = this;

    _this.$uibModal = $uibModal;
}


/**
 *
 */
ClientsController.prototype.create = function()
{
    var instance = this.$uibModal.open(
        {
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'modules/clients/views/modal/client.html',
            controller: 'ClientModalInstController as ctrl',
            size: 'lg'
        }
    );
};
```

Here is modal controller

```
ClientModalInstController.$inject = [
    '$uibModalInstance'
];


/**
 * @constructor
 * @param $uibModalInstance
 */
function ClientModalInstController($uibModalInstance)
{
    var _this = this;

    _this.$uibModalInstance = $uibModalInstance;
}
```

Any idea what could cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: Where are you registering `ClientModalInstController` as a controller?

Comment: That code is above $inject block, i just didnt show it here

Comment: Seems to work ok over here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3UNct38ZGCsvMHTZ4M6?p=preview. Must be something you're missing. What are your module's dependencies?

Comment: I've seen that plnkr and I can't figure out what I'm missing. I've added ui.bootstrap to modul. Wired thing is, that I'm able to open modal, but when I try to inject modal instance, then it breaks

Comment: Try adding the `ng-strict-di` attribute to the element with `ng-app`. It might help point out any errors.

Comment: Could be you're using ui-bootstrap 0.14.2. If so, upgrade to 0.14.3 ~ https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4778

Answer (score 0):

What could be causing the behavior is the following:

`$uibModal.open()` returns a `$modalInstance` which requires a dependency injection of `$uibModalInstance` into the `ClientModalInstController` controller. I can't see the code for `ClientModalInstController`, but it needs to have `$uibModalInstance` injected into it, which is different than `$uibModal`

You can see an example of this in the javascript tab of the Modal example in the ui-bootstrap docs: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Scroll down to the Modal section of the docs and look at the code in the Javascript tab for the `ModalInstanceCtrl` and its injected dependencies.

Comment: I have $uibModalInstance injected, that is the part when it throws an error

Comment: $uibModalInstance is already injected and only that injection is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

@SilvioMarijic this breaks if the items aren't injected correct order. Make sure everything lines up.

CODE EXAMPLE:

```
angular.module('App').controller('YourController', ['$scope', '$http', '$uibModal', 
function ($scope, $http, $uibModal) {

  //CODE HERE

}]);
```

Assume you swapped $http and $uiModal in the constructor (either line) you'll get the error your describing.