# Angular UI Bootstrap Modal: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-modal

This is a bit strange.  When I search this issue online I see many pages of Google results and SO solutions... but none seem to work!

In a nutshell, I am trying to implement AngularUI Bootstrap Modal.  I keep getting the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <- $uibModalInstance <- addEntryCtrl

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="nav-col" ng-controller="navCtrl" style="text-align:right">
      <a class="btn pill" ng-click="open()" aria-hidden="true">Add New</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('nav', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('navCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal) {
  $scope.open = function() {
    var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: true,
      templateUrl: 'addEntry/addEntry.html',
      controller: 'addEntryCtrl',
    });
  };
}]);
```

And finally, here is my modal code:

```
var app = angular.module('addEntry', ['firebase', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('addEntryCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$state', '$uibModalInstance', function($scope, $firebaseObject, $state, $uibModalInstance) {
  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

  $uibModalInstance.close();
}]);
```

Solutions I've tried:

- updated both Angular Bootstrap (Version: 0.14.3) and Angular (v1.4.8)
- changed uibModalInstance to modalInstance
- changed $uibModalInstance to modalInstance
- put my addEntryCtrl inside my ModalInstance

Any thoughts?  This has been driving me up the wall for almost 2 days now.

*** EDIT ***

I should note two things:

1) when I remove $uibModalInstance as a dependency from addEntry, my HTML form submit buttons work just fine and the form looks perfect.  Even the redirect occurs correctly (upon submission).  The problem remains: the modal still stays on the screen and an error is thrown that $uibModalInstance is undefined.  This makes sense since I removed it as a dependency but I obviously still need the modal is close upon submission.

2) Also, I have almost identical code working in another part of my app.  The only difference there is that it's working via a factory.  Otherwise, the code is identical. Thus, I am confident my dependencies are all there and versions are correct.  So. Freaking. Strange.

Thanks!

Comment: Are those code blocks within an IIFE? Otherwise, you're overwriting the `app` variable (could prove troublesome). Also, your second code block contains an unclosed function and array. It's probably a typo or you just omitted the latter parts but you should try to make the code in your questions complete

Comment: Also, I've seen this same error before (http://stackoverflow.com/q/33600137/283366) but that question didn't get any useful answers. FYI, `$uibModalInstance` works fine in my apps

Comment: Any chance you're using ui-bootstrap 0.14.2? `$uibModalInstance` was added in 0.14.3 ~ https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4778

Comment: @Phil thanks for the response!  1) i edited my code to include closing brackets, 2) i included the version of bootstrap and angular..... still no dice :(

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Answer Found!  After hacking away with my friend, we discovered the answer.  I wanted to post it here just in case someone else reads this.

It turns out that we had an ng-controller in our modal window that was in a div tag that wrapped the entire html form that was in the modal.  Previously, this worked fine when our form was NOT in a modal (it had a separate URL) but for some reason it breaks when it is in a modal.  The ng-controller was referencing the `addEntryCtrl`.  Immediately after removing it, the form worked!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'd been looking for the correct answer to this problem, this should be written somewhere in the ui.bootstrap documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Thanks for the update. It helped me on the way to finding an alternate solution allowing me to use `ng-controller` from the view. See my answer for more details!

Comment: Exactly my problem.  Up voting your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Had the exact same problem, your answer finally solved my problem after searching for hours. thanks!

Answer (score 20):

The problem was that you were specifying a (or double) controller(s) in 2 places- when opening a modal and inside a template - this is not needed. ***Remove ng-controller from a template*** and things will work as expected.Trust me,it will work.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This is exactly the problem I'm facing. Since I just want to use the directive, so I don't have my own controller. I put the controller of the directive into the tag, it caused the problem. Removing the ng-controller attribute resolved it perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This answer it totally wrong - Check this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s8bLdg2d/ or this plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/FElOoLllZmT7kaGVtz5V?p=preview

Comment: This is the best answer. Keep it up.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that if you specify the controller inside the html template (with `ng-controller="..."`) it will not resolve the `$uibModalInstance`. Specifying the controller from the call to `$uibModal.open({controller="...", ...})` will allow it to resolve correctly.

Since you only need the `dismiss()` and `close()` methods, you can get them from `$scope` (named `$dismiss` and `$close`) instead, since that will resolve correctly in both ways of instantiating the controller.

```
var app = angular.module('addEntry', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('addEntryCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $scope.$dismiss('cancel');
    };

    $scope.$close();
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to reference a controller that is part of a separate module. In order for this to work, you need to inject your secondary module (addEntry) into your main module (nav):

```
var app = angular.module('nav', ['ui.bootstrap', 'addEntry']);
```

Comment: Good advice but that's certainly not the source of OP's error

Comment: great advice.  i added it.  didnt solve my issue though :(

Comment: @BenjaminHoffman did you forget to include the script(angular UI Bootstrap) file?

Comment: @NPToita if you mean the ang UI bootstrap dependency... yes i did via bower. ;)

Comment: your code seems fine when it put it in plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fZKP82RmP0q3L0mXW6WV?p=preview. so I'm suspecting it's a referencing problem.

Comment: when you say its a referencing problem, can you be more specific? i searched google for that but no dice.... more details would be great @NPToita thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you use $uibModal.open() (see lower) and specify explicitly the **controller** name, you shouldn't put the directive **ng-controller** in the template. 
That cause the error. No **ng-controller** in the **View** !

```
 var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: true,
  templateUrl: 'addEntry/addEntry.html',
  controller: 'addEntryCtrl',
});
```