# angular ui bootstrap: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appMainProvider <- appMain

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-bootstrap

I m currently trying to open an AngularUI Bootstrap Modal. Somehow, I keep getting the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appMainProvider <- appMain

I search online and found several "solution" but none of them seem to work (or perhaps i m doing something wrong). One of the solution i found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33930325/angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-injectorunpr-unknown-provider-uibmodalinstance/33980575).

This is my `main js controller`:

```
module.exports = function(appMain, name) {

    appMain.controller(name, mainCtrl);

    mainCtrl.$inject = ['$state', 'mainDataService', 'dnnVariables', '$uibModal'];

    function mainCtrl($state, mainDataService, dnnVariables, $uibModal) {

        var vm = this;

        function fullAnswer() {
            var source = require("../ViewAnswer/viewAnswer.html");
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: source,
                controller: require("../ViewAnswer/viewAnswer.controller.js"),
                controllerAs: 'viewAnswerCtrl',
                backdrop: 'static'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This opens the modal. The modal html is as following (barely anything for testing purpose)

```
something
```

The `modal js controller` is as following:

```
module.exports = function (appMain, name) {

appMain.controller(name, viewAnswerCtrl);

viewAnswerCtrl.$inject = ['$state', 'mainDataService', 'dnnVariables', "$uibModalInstance"];

function viewAnswerCtrl($state, mainDataService, dnnVariables, $uibModalInstance) {

    var vm = this;

    }
}
```

Note: I'm using `angular-ui-bootstrap 2.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example `mainCtrl` is not controller function but some wrapper function that defines a controller. It is likely supposed to be used as:

```
mainCtrl(appMain, name);
```

instead of

```
appMain.controller(name, mainCtrl);
```

There's no benefit in wrapping controllers in `module.exports = function (appMain, name) {...}`. It should be preferably omitted, and `angular.module(...)` should be used instead of `appMain` variable.

Comment: It should affect the error. The error results from that you pass `function (appMain, name) {` function as argument to `controller`, etc. If you do this in several places, all of them should be fixed.

Comment: missedtypes something. fixed it. Thanks